# Get screen size out of Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to know the screen size in a class which extends ArrayAdapter class. I can't use getWindowManager method because my class doesn't extend Activity class. What could I do?

Comment: using `DisplayMetrics` get device height and width and then pass it though your class

Answer (score 2):

using `DisplayMatrics`

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    double x = Math.pow(metrics.widthPixels/metrics.xdpi,2);
    double y = Math.pow(metrics.heightPixels/metrics.ydpi,2);
    double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

also get width and height pixels as below

```
double heightpixel = metrics.heightPixels;
double widthpixel = metrics.widthPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

use WindowManager

```
WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
Display display = window.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context to the custom ArrayAdapter and then get the size from it

Like this:

```
public class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public TestAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> tests) {
       super(context, 0, tests);
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
       Context ctx = getContext();
       DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
       int width = metrics.widthPixels;
       int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use getWindowManager() method in activity class and get screen width and height after pass width and height in adapter constructor or use shared prefrence.